# Why does this sentence mean what it means?

Tags: grammar

> なんて言えばいいのか分からない

Means "I don't know what to say" but why does it mean that?

Is there an explanation into why this means that.

Comment: Is there anything in particular that you don't understand?

Comment: 言えばいい means "If I say it, it's good" right?
How does なんて effect that? I understand the rest except for なんて言えばいい

Comment: I think that in this case なんて is interchangeable with なんか(何か) so the literal meaning would be "I don't know if anything I say would be good to say" http://maggiesensei.com/2013/09/02/how-to-use-%E3%81%AA%E3%82%93%E3%81%A6nante/

Comment: Thank you Felipe, I understand it now. That was what I was struggling to grasp.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly "分からない（I don't know）"

then I don't know what?

"なんて言えばいいのか"

"言えばいいのか" could be directly translated into "how to say."

but this Japanese sntence "なんて言えばいいのか" menas "何を言えばいいのか."

We Japanese understand "なんて言えばいいのか" not as "how to say" but "what to say."